# Python - Download a csv file in website without link

Tags: python, request, urllib

I am having problem on downloading a csv file using python.

File Location: https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx?ucode=00001

The download button "export to csv" show javascript without a link.

How can I download the file? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you'd be able to use JS, the target website has jQuery included so you could just call
    `$('[title="Export to CSV"]')[0].click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the URL provided you cannot extract the download link directly. However, downloading the CSV yields the following URL:
`https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx?action=csv&type=3&ucode=00001`. Making it predictable.

So depending on your usecase, you can use that? The values for `ucode` can be extracted from select box in your first url.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a link: https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx?action=csv&type=3&ucode=00001

A simple requests.get() call will give you the file:

```
import requests
filedata = requests.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx?action=csv&type=3&ucode=00001').text
```