# How can I download a file that doesn't actually have a download link?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, download, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests and BeautifulSoup to search for and download specific files, which I know how to do when the element's `href` link is "normal". However, for this project, the element's `href` is unusual (just a "#"), and doing a `request.get()` for any of the items within the `<a>` tag yields errors.

[Here's the actual webpage itself](https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/caf63b5f-2218-42e5-8e55-9f88673477e7)

Here's an inspection of the page:

[image: webpage/inspections screenshot]

And here's a snippet of the code that's parsing it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/caf63b5f-2218-42e5-8e55-9f88673477e7"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
a_list = list(enumerate(soup.find_all('a')))
for i, link in a_list:
    if ".ebc.gz" in link.get_text():
        response = requests.get(link["href"])
        test_file = open(f"{path}/test.ebc.gz", 'wb')
        test_file.write(response.content)
```

Clicking on the filename on the webpage yields the direct download I'm looking for.

Someone suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278283/python-download-a-csv-file-in-website-without-link), to someone with a similar problem, that their download actually *DID* yield a link, but I can't figure out where or how this person saw that.

Comment: I don't think you can find the file to download with the hyperlink given in your webpage. For such data security reasons, the page has been developed with wherein the details of filename is being sent as a parameter for making it available for download through function call in the background script.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, so I'm basically out of luck regarding downloading it like this? Maybe I'll give Selenium a try... I was hoping to avoid that though

Comment: You might check out chrome developer tools and see what link is being requested and any other special parameters when you click on the desired resource.